# JVisualVM lies: "Not supported for this JVM" while it is

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, jvisualvm

App A, ran from IntelliJ, has CPU usage and I can look at threads. App B has no Threads tab and CPU usage shows "Not supported for this JVM". Both apps are ran **with same JVM**. Why / what happened?

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.8.0_101, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre

I can take a thread dump with `jstack`.

Apps are simple command-line programs, not larger than 10 classes. One app uses finalization, if it matters.

I started both apps from IntelliJ Idea, via Run. App A when started from CLI (via `java FinalizerTest`) and looked at with `jvisualvm` had Threads and CPU usage, despite not having it previously. This is still the same JVM that runs it, so I guess this is Intellij problem?

If I can provide more information, freely ask.

Comment: Can you give us an excerpt on how you start both apps? (java -jar...)

Comment: Both in the same manner, from intellij, via run. I just started the problematic one from console via java nameOfClass and this had no problems: threads were visible and CPU usage as well in same jvisualvm. :O

Comment: Thanks @dbalakirev, turns out to be Intellij's problem, I guess?

Comment: IDEA runs them in "run configurations" so maybe some different options are used. If it's in the same IDEA project at least the SDK is set. If not in same project check that as well maybe.